# Карты яндекс или гугл, как такое сделать? (есть строка с адресом - нужно получить карту с отметкой)

Tags: google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api

У меня есть строка с адресом

Нужно отправить запрос и получить в ответ карту с отметкой на ней этого адреса

Знаю что у яндекса можно вручную щелкать, но мне требуется именно чтобы программа искала адреса и рисовала карту, адресов очень много

кто знает как решить эту проблему?

Comment: для google это называется geocode api http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/yJb48/

Answer (score 2):

В Яндекс картах это называется геокодер.
Вот пример из документации:

```
var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode(
    // Строка с адресом, который нужно геокодировать
    "Москва", {
        /* Опции поиска:
           - область поиска */
        boundedBy: myMap.getBounds(),
        // - искать только в этой области
        strictBounds: true,
        // - требуемое количество результатов
        results: 1
    }
);

/* После того, как поиск вернул результат, вызывается callback-функция */myGeocoder.then(
function (res) {
    /* Размещение полученной коллекции 
       геообъектов на карте */
    myMap.geoObjects.add(res.geoObjects);
}
```

);